# Loading JSON file and parsing

Tags: json, python-3.x

My input JSON (created using notebook) is as below:

```
{"title": "Item number - This is of no use"}
{"title": "Did you find Ram's sale application?"}
```

When I load and read the JSON file and read the contents, the string becomes as below:

```
with open(data, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        test = json.load(file)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
```

The string becomes as below in df column: How to prevent and preserve the original contents as "Item number - This is of no use" and "Did you find Ram's sale application?"

```
Item number û This is of no use
Did you find RamÆs sale application?
```

I tried removing double and single quotes also. But still doesn't help.

Comment: Did you make sure to also use utf-8 when writing the file?

Comment: It was manually constructed in the notepad.

Comment: And with which encoding did you save it? If you mean Windows Notepad, I think it doesn't allow specifying the encoding (so it presumably uses the default windows encoding and not utf-8). I would suggest using a different text editor (e.g. Notepad++).